# Как получить все атрибуты из init?

Tags: python, классы

Есть класс `Worker`

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, age, work) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.work = work 

    def say_hello(self):
        print(f"Привет, я {self.name}")

    
oleg = Worker('Олег', 43, "Танкист")
```

Хочу получить список всех атрибутов, которые объявил в `__init__`. Пока в голову пришло только такое решение

```
list_attr = [x for x in dir(oleg) if not x.startswith('__')]

# ['age', 'name', 'work']
```

Может, есть какой-то метод или более лаконичный способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `__dict__`

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, age, work) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.work = work  

oleg = Worker('Олег', 43, "Танкист")

list_attr = [attr for attr in oleg.__dict__ if not callable(getattr(oleg, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]

# ['name', 'age', 'work']
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, для чего там проверка на callable и дандер. Я попробовал вызвать `list(oleg.__dict__.keys())` и получил такой же лист с тремя атрибутами. Для чего тогда if'ы в списковом включении?

Comment: @DarkSpace проверка на callable для того, чтобы не выводить то, что callable. Вы проверили на одном элементарном примере, неудивительно, что никакой разницы. Станет ваш класс побольше, разницу увидите. Добавьте туда какую-нибудь функцию.

Comment: @Эникейщик Добавил один метод и всё равно результат не изменился. (В вопросе конкретизировал класс)

Comment: По сравнению с чем? С этим кодом? Разумеется, не изменился. Сравнивать надо с кодом из вашего вопроса.

Comment: @Эникейщик, я с ним и сравнивал

Comment: не может быть. Ваш код выводит функции, этот код не выводит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144941/discussion-between-dark-space-and-).